# Write to database a LocalDate field in specific format

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having trouble writing an `Entity` which includes `LocalDate` fields to Postgresql in the format of `"dd-MM-yyyy"`

My Entity looks like this.

```
@Entity
public class DataUpload {

  @Id
  @NonNull
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private final String clinic;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
  private final LocalDate startDate;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
  private final LocalDate endDate;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private final long numRows;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
  private final LocalDate dateUploaded;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private final boolean processed;

  public DataUpload() {
    clinic = "SuperDuperClinic";
    startDate = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.JULY, 5);
    endDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JULY, 5);
    numRows = 500;
    dateUploaded = LocalDate.now();
    processed = true;
  }
//getters setters
}
```

It seems that `@DateTimeFormat` Annotation has no effect as the columns filled in database look like this.
[image: wrong date format]

How to format a `LocalDate` object to specific pattern so that it can be persisted in the database exactly as I want to?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a `@DateTimeFormat` does not influence at a date representation at any DBMS. According to a [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) :

> @DateTimeFormat declares that a field or method parameter should be formatted as a
>   date or time

So it means that this annotation allows you to format date values on the fly for a web output as like as a `@JsonSerialize` from the `Jackson` framework. Appearence of your dates in a DBMS manager depends only on settings in the DB manager, moreover any dates in a database are keeped as decimal values and each DB manager displays them only by its settings